# the meaning of a ruby regular expression

Tags: ruby, expression

```
string=http://abc.com.vn/12345
string =~ /.*\/([0-9]+)/
number = $~[1]
```

With the above lines of code using Ruby regular expression, the variable "number" will have the value '12345'. However, I do NOT understand clearly the meaning of ~ /.*/([0-9]+)/ and  $~[1] used above. Could you please help explain for me. Thanks so much.

Comment: That is not a valid Ruby expression.

Comment: You are missing quotes on the first line, I guess? Regular expressions look arcane, but are easy to understand in general - you'll need a few hours to get to grips with them, and they are useful to know for all sorts of work, not just Ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Ruby Doc, the `$~` global variable is equivalent to the `last_match` method. [Source](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Regexp.html#method-c-last_match).

The previous line, `=~ /.*\/([0-9]+)/` checks to see if there is a match between the string stored in `string` and the regex on the right side. `=~` will return the numerical position where there is a match in that string, or `nil` if there was no match.

Answer (score 1):

You should really read the minimum about regexs in ruby before posting a question here but this is to get you started:

```
=~ is the match operator similar to the match operator in perl
$~ is an array holding the various elements of the match
```